# How Can I Improve The Look Of This Transition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, transition

I am trying to translate two buttons down and off-screen after one is clicked. I have it working, but it is very choppy. How can I make this transition more fluid? 
-I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
-The language I am using is c#
Here is my transition code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int speed_increase = 100;


        if(sleep_button.Top <= 800 || calibrate_button.Top <= 800)
        {
            sleep_button.Top += speed_increase;
            calibrate_button.Top += speed_increase;

        }
    }
```

I have my timer interval set to 1ms too, just because I am aware the larger interval the choppier it becomes. I have been looking all day for a button transition tutorial and found none. And if this isn't possible can somebody sent me a tutorial for button fade outs? Thanks everyone

Comment: What platform is this? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: That's not a platform. What is the project type?

Comment: My fault, Windows Form Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timing choice is off.  1ms is too granular.  Try something around the 20ms mark, this will cause your code to run 50 times per second, which is rather closely aligned with common refresh rates of around 50hz.

How far do the buttons need to scroll?  How long should it take?

Assume X is the distance to scroll, and Y is the time in seconds.  The number of iterations is Y * 50 (50 times per second), and the distance per step is X / Y.

X = 200 pixels.
Y = 2 seconds.

Distance per step is:
X / (Y * 50)
200 / (2 * 50)
200 / 100
== 2

If you want to scroll 200 pixels over 2 seconds, you want to add 2 to the Y position of each button on each iteration.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I need to transition 700 pixels in 1 second. So 700/(1*50) == 14, I changed my timer to 20ms and my speed_change variable to 14, but the animation takes well over two seconds and is still very choppy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your program doing other significant work while the transition is happening?

Comment: No, I have switched over to WPF. Should be able to handle transitions much better, and it can run on Windows

Answer (score 0):

How about hiding it altogether?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sleep_button.Visible = false;
        calibrate_button.Visible = false;
    }
```